# How can I send data or event info from Javascript to Default.cs (Asp.net)?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, ajax

How can I send data or event info from Javascript to Default.cs (ASP.NET)? is it ajax?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to create an AJAX call to Default.aspx.

Using [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com):

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Default.aspx",
    data: "first=John&last=Doe",
    success: function(msg){
        alert( "Data saved: " + msg );
    }
});
```